# Autodesk Forge retrieve/update custom attributes

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

We are using BIM360 docs and we have defined several custom attributes to tag those files uploaded into the docs folder. Now we are having trouble to get those custom attribute using forge API, `projects/:project_id/items/:item_id` endpoint only returns those default attribute like file name/description but for custom attributes it's not included in the response, neither can i update those custom attributes use PATCH to update those custom attributes.

Does Autodesk Forge API support getting/updating custom attributes?

The attribute node I got from the item API looks like this:

```
"attributes": {
                "name": "somefile.rvt",
                "displayName": "somefile.rvt",
                "createTime": "2018-08-02T18:16:59.0000000Z",
                "createUserId": "creatorID",
                "createUserName": "usercreate",
                "lastModifiedTime": "2018-11-01T10:46:20.0000000Z",
                "lastModifiedUserId": "userid",
                "lastModifiedUserName": "username",
                "versionNumber": 1,
                "extension": {
                    "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:Document",
                    "version": "1.0",
                    "schema": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/versions:autodesk.bim360:Document-1.0"
                    },
                    "data": {
                        "processState": "PROCESSING_COMPLETE",
                        "viewableId": "id",
                        "viewableGuid": "id",
                        "viewableName": "Existing",
                        "sourceFileName": "somefile.rvt"
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the information of folder/file is provided by Forge Data Management API, this API is used as a common access to many different Autodesk SAAS app like A360 Personal, BIM 360 Team, Fusion Team (formerly known as A360 Team), BIM 360 Docs.

Unfortunately, since the custom attributes are specified only for BIM360 Docs(correct me if I am wrong), so the Folder/Item API of Forge Date Management does not provide that information yet. I am also checking with our engineering team to see if any other information, or this could be a good API request, will update this if I got more information.

Comment: Thanks, i will also contact Autodesk support and have the result posted here.

Comment: It would to useful to know if this is possible, as I would also like the ability to update and retrieve custom attributes. It would also be useful to create attributes via the Forge API as well.

Comment: Thanks all, in short, this is not possible at this moment, but this is a good request and I have already forwarded your comments to our internal team. Please accept the answer if it answers your question.